# C# static method called only on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, static-methods

I have this static method, which is called somewhere on startup of every WebApi method (using MVC core, WebApi project):

```
private static object syncObj = new object();
private static string myProp;

public static string MyStaticMethod()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        if (myProp == null)
        {
            myProp = Utils.GetMyPropFromRegistry();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myProp))
            {
                throw new MyException("myProp value not set");
            }
        }
    }

    return myProp;
}
```

When the application starts and the first time this method is called, I receive an exception, since I do not have a proper value written in the registry (a call from `Utils.GetMyPropFromRegistry` returns null). This is all OK. But, if I add value to the registry, while the application is still running (in debug mode), this method does not get called ever again. It actually returns the same exception message through WebApi as the first time, just debugger does not stop on any breakpoint (which it did on application startup). If I examine the stack trace, it shows correctly where this exception occurred, it just doesn't stop there and it doesn't read the new value from the registry.

It seems like C# (or ASP.NET Core), somehow remembers that method throws an exception and it doesn't even execute code?

Is there anything special about static methods that throw an exception on startup? Or maybe it has something to do with the lock statement? I've used static methods before, but never run into such an issue.

Places where this is called:

```
// 1: Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(ConfigureJwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var data = MyStaticMethod();
                // Do something with data
            });
}

// 2: WebApiController.cs:
public async Task<ActionResult<LoginResult>> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    var data = MyStaticMethod();
    var result = (do something with data)
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How did you call this method and where?

Comment: The first time is called inside "JwtBearerExtensions.AddJwtBearer" (in startup.cs) inside configureOptions Action and then on specific (Login) WebAPI request.

Comment: You need to show everywhere this is being called. So we can figure out the scope of the call.

Comment: Static constructors are called only once, and that is when the type is first referenced. Are you possibly calling this static method of yours from a static constructor? Or are you calling this method to initialize a static field of yours? Becuase in that case, which is very familiar to me, your static constructor (or static field initialization) occurs only once and if an error occurs, will never be called again.

Comment: Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typeinitializationexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is not called from a static constructor (it is called on startup within AddJwtBearer method and then on specific WebApi call), although it does try to initialize private static field myProp. Probably thats why this fails the all the times after the first call.

Comment: I've also added places where this is called to the question, if its of any help.